# Webflow to google sheet using Zapier webhooks

Tags: webhooks, spreadsheet, zapier, webflow

I am new to Zapier and webhooks.
I want to add the new recods into the google spreadhseet via Webflow based on some `if else` condition using Zapier webhooks. Basically i want to add the records according the weeks (time) when they are added.

How can i achive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the records in google sheets just refer this link: -
[WebFlowIntegration](https://zapier.com/apps/google-sheets/integrations/webflow)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).